# How to access childview items from a linearlayout in android?

Tags: android, web-services, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have a linear layout with custom items like the image:

[image]

that is filled by a webservice, how do I gain access to "delete" `textview` and to radio button to perform an `onclick` and `onchecked` listeners?

My activity starts loading the data of the webservice and puts in a linear layout "n" childs of every response that gets from the webservice, I want to enable the click and checked listeners depending on the position of the child in the listview.

Thnx.

Adapter.

```
public class NewPaymentsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Payments> {

    private ViewHolder holder;

    public NewPaymentsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Payments> newpayments) {
        super(context, 0, newpayments);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final Payments payments = getItem(position);
        if (convertView == null){
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.new_payments_item, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.rbPayments = (RadioButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rbPayments);
            holder.tvPaymentsDelete = (MyTitleFontTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvPaymentsDelete);
            holder.tvPaymentsTitle = (MyTitleFontTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvPaymentsTitle);
            holder.tvPaymentsDesc = (MyFontTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvPaymentsDesc);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.tvPaymentsTitle.setText("Tarjeta");
        holder.tvPaymentsDesc.setText("**** **** **** " + payments.getLastfour());
        if (Boolean.parseBoolean(payments.getIsdefault()) == true){
            holder.rbPayments.setChecked(true);
        } else {
            holder.rbPayments.setChecked(false);
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        RadioButton rbPayments;
        MyTitleFontTextView tvPaymentsDelete, tvPaymentsTitle;
        MyFontTextView tvPaymentsDesc;
    }
```

Parser

```
public ArrayList<Payments> parseNewPayments(String response, ArrayList<Payments> list) {

        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
            if (jsonObject.getBoolean(KEY_SUCCESS)) {
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("payments");
                if (jsonArray.length() > 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        Payments newpayments = new Payments();

                        newpayments.setId(object.getInt("id"));
                        newpayments.setLastfour(object.getString("last_four"));
                        newpayments.setIsdefault(object.getString("is_default"));
                        list.add(newpayments);
                    }
                }

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Model

```
public class Payments {

    private int id;
    private String isdefault, lastfour;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getLastfour() {
        return lastfour;
    }

    public void setLastfour(String lastfour) {
        this.lastfour = lastfour;
    }

    public String getIsdefault() {
        return isdefault;
    }

    public void setIsdefault(String isdefault) {
        this.isdefault = isdefault;
    }

   }
```

Activity

```
this.pContent.parseNewPayments(response, newPaymentsList);
                    newPaymentsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    adaptercount = Integer.valueOf(newPaymentsAdapter.getCount());
                    for (int i = 0; i < adaptercount; i++) {
                        View item = newPaymentsAdapter.getView(i, null, null);
                        layNewPayments.addView(item);
                    }
```

Here is my code, the activity displays correctly the data from the WS, now with this i want to do a "delete" and "select default" method with the textview and the radio button, passing the param

```
Card card = new Card(),
id = card.getid()
```

and executing a http POST, but i cant access the child textview or radio button to perform that.

Comment: Please add relevant code.

Comment: Is there any reason why a `ListView` cannot be used?

Comment: I don't use listview because when I make a change in a radio button an then i scroll it, it lost the checked value (recycles) and with the Linearlayout i dont have that problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use findViewById method of View class.

For example,

```
LinearLayout ll = findViewById(R.id.parentLayout);
int childcount = ll.getChildCount();
for (int i=0; i < childcount; i++){
    LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout) ll.getChildAt(i);
    TextView delete = (TextView) l.findViewById(R.id.delete);

    delete.setOnClickListener(...);
}
```

Comment: That's ok but that only gives me access when i have only one child, but some values change in my code when i have more.